# Errors while deploying Fastapi with Lambda and Docker

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, fastapi, aws-serverless

I am trying to deploy my API in Lambda, but I receive the following error:

```
OpenBLAS WARNING - could not determine the L2 cache size on this system, assuming 256k
OpenBLAS WARNING - could not determine the L2 cache size on this system, assuming 256k
START RequestId: afcef2d3-c9fe-47f8-834e-fb57c450e6f3 Version: $LATEST
[INFO]  2022-11-13T22:55:34.944Z    afcef2d3-c9fe-47f8-834e-fb57c450e6f3    Waiting for application startup.
[INFO]  2022-11-13T22:55:34.944Z    afcef2d3-c9fe-47f8-834e-fb57c450e6f3    LifespanCycleState.STARTUP:  'lifespan.startup.complete' event received from application.
[INFO]  2022-11-13T22:55:34.944Z    afcef2d3-c9fe-47f8-834e-fb57c450e6f3    Application startup complete.
[INFO]  2022-11-13T22:55:34.945Z    afcef2d3-c9fe-47f8-834e-fb57c450e6f3    Waiting for application shutdown.
[INFO]  2022-11-13T22:55:34.945Z    afcef2d3-c9fe-47f8-834e-fb57c450e6f3    LifespanCycleState.SHUTDOWN: 'lifespan.shutdown.complete' event received from application.
[ERROR] KeyError: 'path'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/app.py", line 34, in handler
    response = asgi_handler(event, context)
  File "/var/task/mangum/adapter.py", line 101, in __call__
    scope = self.create_scope(event, context)
  File "/var/task/mangum/adapter.py", line 148, in create_scope
    path = event["path"]
END RequestId: afcef2d3-c9fe-47f8-834e-fb57c450e6f3
REPORT RequestId: afcef2d3-c9fe-47f8-834e-fb57c450e6f3  Duration: 12529.69 ms   Billed Duration: 12530 ms   Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 163 MB
```

The structure of my code is as follows:

```
-app
---routes/
---__init__.py
---app.py
-Dockerfile
-package.json
-requirements.txt
-serverless.yaml
```

Where my app.py contains the following logic:

```
import uvicorn
import os

from fastapi import FastAPI
from mangum import Mangum

from routes import main

###############################################################################
#   Application object                                                        #
###############################################################################
stage = os.environ.get('STAGE', None)
openapi_prefix = f"/{stage}" if stage else "/"

app = FastAPI(title = "XX", 
              description = "XX",
              root_path=openapi_prefix
              )

###############################################################################
#   Routers configuration                                                     #
###############################################################################

app.include_router(main.router, prefix='/metrics', tags=['metrics'])

###############################################################################
#   Handler for AWS Lambda                                                    #
###############################################################################

def handler(event, context):
    event['requestContext'] = {}  # Adds a dummy field; mangum will process this fine
    
    asgi_handler = Mangum(app)
    response = asgi_handler(event, context)

    return response

###############################################################################
#   Run the self contained application                                        #
###############################################################################

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

And the Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8
# Copy function code
COPY ./app ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
# Install the function's dependencies using file requirements.txt
# from your project folder.
COPY ./requirements.txt  .
RUN  pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}" -U --no-cache-dir
# Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the Dockerfile)
CMD [ "app.handler" ]
```

There is nothing special in the serverless.yaml, as it is aa standard format to deploy lambda with Docker.

I am trying to deploy an API using FastApi, Docker and serverless. However, I cannot make it happen as the handler keeps failing. I have make it work without Docker, but once Docker is introduced, the code did not work.

Comment: Please read: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: this is not a full output of error, could you provide full traceback log?

Comment: ... and it seems the issue is about using the Mangum library. However, as svfat said we need all the details of the traceback log.

Comment: Full traceback log added.

Comment: How are you invoking your function in this case? There's a "path" missing in the event, so I'm guessing you're doing some direct invocation instead of hitting the APIGW endpoint, correct? You cannot do that, or you have to pass a dummy APIGW event as a payload in such cases